# How to pull text from this string of data

Tags: c#, regex

I need to pull the city and state out string of data that look as follows:

```
8 mi SSW of Newtown, PA
10 mi SE of Milwaukee, WI
29 Miles E of Orlando, FL
```

As of right now I am passing each string individually into a method

`string statusLocation = "8 mi SSW of Newtown, PA"`

etc. one at a time.

What would be the best way to search this string for the city state? I was thinking either regex or substring and index of the comma etc. I wasn’t quite sure what kind of issues I would run into if a state is 3 characters or a city has a comma in it because this is Canada data as well and I am not sure how they abbreviate stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a

```
string str = "8 mi SSW of Newtown, PA";
var parts = str.Split(new[] {' '}, 5);
```

parts then looks like this: { "8", "mi", "SSW", "of", "Newtown, PA" }, and you can access the "Newtown, PA" easily with parts[4].

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression:

```
of (.*), ([a-zA-Z]{2})$
```

That will capture everything after the `of`, up a comma that is followed by a space then two letters, then a line ending. For example:

```
var regex = new Regex("of (.*), ([a-zA-Z]{2})$");
var strings = new[]
                    {
                        "8 mi SSW of Newtown, PA",
                        "10 mi SE of Milwaukee, WI",
                        "29 Miles E of Orlando, FL"
                    };

foreach (var str in strings)
{
    var match = regex.Match(str);
    var city = match.Groups[1];
    var state = match.Groups[2];
    Console.Out.WriteLine("state = {0}", state);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("city = {0}", city);
}
```

This of course assumes some consistency with the data, like the state being two letters.

Comment: I came up with `^(.*?)of (.*), (\w\w)$`.

Comment: anything seems a far reach for state names, maybe [a-zA-Z]